# Laravel returns MethodNotAllowedHttpException on routing does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, post, get, routes

I created a route for buy an item in laravel 5.7

```
Route::post('/buy/item', "userController@buy_item")->name('buy_item_form');
```

Everything works fine but when I refresh the page(replace to GET Request) I got an 
**MethodNotAllowedHttpException**.
The GET route not exist, Its must return an 404 error.
I dont understant why its return me this exception.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a post, with post you have a @csrf token. when you click on refresh, you are doing a GET method instead of a post and for hence you get the method not allow exception. If you are not sending data you can change it to a get [Route::get] method.

If you want to accept the 2 methods [post,get] to have a better experience and manage the possible errors. You can accept the 2 methods on the route like:

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'/buy/item', 'userController@buy_item')->name('buy_item_form');
```

And on the controller, define what to do base on the method.

```
if (Request::isMethod('get')){
    // redirect user
}

if (Request::isMethod('post')){
    // do logic for post method
}
```

Comment: I didn't create a GET route.
so why I got an exception on GET request if the route not exist.

This should return me an 404 error.

Comment: when you refresh or go to a page is a **get** method, if you submit data and set the method on the form to post, it will post the info instead of get. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: I mean that I created a Post Route And When I write the url of the post route on the url adress bar in my browser(Make a get Request) its return an exception and not 404 error.

I can make a get route thet do abort(404) but is not must be happen anyway?

Comment: add this to your code, and you will see that you are doing a get on refresh

Route::get('/buy/item', function(){
   return "Get Request";
});

Comment: I can make this: Route::get('/buy/item', function(){return abort(404)});
But my question is why is not happend automaticly.

Comment: replying to your first post, you have a route "/buy/item" but the method is incorrect post instead of get [ as of laravel error.]

Comment: 1. your debug is set to true. so you see raw error messages
2. The route is there regardless, the "post" is specifying what action is allowed on that route

Comment: So I must to create a Get route too although I don`t need it?

Comment: I updated my answer to give you an example to manage the 2 methods.

Comment: I don`t want to manage 2 methods.
just the post method.
The get method not return 404 automaticly if the route not exist?

Comment: what do you want to return for the get method ?

Comment: 404 - Page not found

Comment: under the **Request::isMethod::get**  add  **abort(404);**